# Why debug in Intellij Idea not working with no error code

Tags: sockets, debugging, intellij-idea

The debugger is not running tried everything but still, the same error comes up every time.

The code is a simple practice code for practicing oops properties.

[image]

Comment: There is no error. Debugger works as expected. Did you forget to set a breakpoint? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot doesn't show any errors. This is a normal behavior when debugger didn't hit any breakpoints. Your application just completes and exits.

Please [refer to the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html#setting-breakpoints) and make sure you didn't forget to set a breakpoint before starting the debugger.

[image]